# Ubuntu One FIles running on Android 2.3 won't auto-upload pictures

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am running the Ubuntu One Files (latest version) on my Droid X with Android 2.3. During the install, I chose the upload all pictures option which did not upload any of my files. I have the <kbd>auto-upload</kbd> and <kbd>immediately</kbd> boxes checked in settings. When I take a photo, it still does not auto-upload. I can manually add photos (one at a time) through OI Files to Ubuntu One Files and it syncs to the cloud; however not to my desktop Pictures-DROIDX folder running Ubuntu 11.04 - all other folders work on the desktop except for `Pictures` which is another issue.

I can find no way to configure Ubuntu One Files to ensure it is monitoring my dcim/Camera folder on my SD card which is where my camera stores pictures taken from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably Droid X has a lowercase /mnt/sdcard/dcim (instead of standard "DCIM") folder name. If that's the case, it was the issue stopping the pictures from auto-uploading. (If that's not the case, please let me know :) .)

Please follow this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/+bug/872021

The fix has been committed, we should be releasing Ubuntu One Files 1.0.4 shortly :)